# How to use PHP Ajax multiple file uploading ,multiple file Description and insert Database?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

PHP Ajax multiple file uploading ,file Description  and insert Database?
Means Photo album.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot upload file using ajax, use some plugin e.g. [`uplodify`](http://www.uploadify.com/)

the reason is javascript cannot access the contents of the file/files on the client machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can "fake" an asynchronous upload by posting your form to a hidden iframe

```
<form action="/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_frame">
    <input type="file" name="file1" />
    <input type="file" name="file2" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<iframe src="/blank.html" style="display: none;" name="upload_frame"></iframe>
```